# Find the Convex Hull of a set of 2D points

Tags: code-golf, geometry

When you hammer a set of nails into a wooden board and wrap a rubber band around them, you get a [Convex Hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

[image]

Your mission, should you decide to accept it, is to find the [Convex Hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of a given set of 2D points.

---

Some rules:

- Write it as a function, the point's list coordinates (in any format you want) is
  the argument
- The output must be the list of points in the convex hull listed
  clockwise or anticlockwise, starting at any of them
- The output list can be in any reasonable format where each point's coordinates are clearly distinguishable. (For example NOT a one dim list { 0.1, 1.3, 4, ...})
- If three or more points in a segment of the convex hull are
  aligned, only the two extremes should be kept on the output

Sample data:

#### Sample 0

Input:

```
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {1, 3}}
```

Output:

```
{{3, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 1}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
(The figures are just illustrative)

#### Sample 1

Input:

```
{{4.4, 14}, {6.7, 15.25}, {6.9, 12.8}, {2.1, 11.1}, {9.5, 14.9}, 
 {13.2, 11.9}, {10.3, 12.3}, {6.8, 9.5}, {3.3, 7.7}, {0.6, 5.1}, {5.3, 2.4}, 
 {8.45, 4.7}, {11.5, 9.6}, {13.8, 7.3}, {12.9, 3.1}, {11, 1.1}}
```

Output:

```
{{13.8, 7.3}, {13.2, 11.9}, {9.5, 14.9}, {6.7, 15.25}, {4.4, 14}, 
 {2.1, 11.1}, {0.6, 5.1}, {5.3, 2.4}, {11, 1.1}, {12.9, 3.1}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Sample 2

Input:

```
{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}, {0.68957, 0.283647}, {0.909487, 0.644276}, 
 {0.0361877, 0.803816}, {0.583004, 0.91555}, {-0.748169, 0.210483}, 
 {-0.553528, -0.967036}, {0.316709, -0.153861}, {-0.79267, 0.585945},
 {-0.700164, -0.750994}, {0.452273, -0.604434}, {-0.79134, -0.249902}, 
 {-0.594918, -0.397574}, {-0.547371, -0.434041}, {0.958132, -0.499614}, 
 {0.039941, 0.0990732}, {-0.891471, -0.464943}, {0.513187, -0.457062}, 
 {-0.930053, 0.60341}, {0.656995, 0.854205}}
```

Output:

```
{{1, -1}, {1, 1}, {0.583004, 0.91555}, {0.0361877, 0.803816}, 
 {-0.930053, 0.60341}, {-0.891471, -0.464943}, {-0.700164, -0.750994}, 
 {-0.553528, -0.967036}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Standard code-golf rules apply. No ad-hoc geometry libraries. Shorter code wins.

**Edit 1**

We are looking for an algorithmic answer here, not a convex hull finder pre-programmed routine like [this one in MatLab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) or [this one in Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ComputationalGeometry/tutorial/ComputationalGeometry.html)

**Edit 2**

Answering comments and additional info:

1. You can assume the input list contains the minimum number of points
   that suits you. But you must ensure proper treatment of aligned (sub)sets.
2. You may find repeated points in the input list
3. The maximum number of points should be limited only by the available memory
4. Re "floating point": You need to be able to process input lists with
   decimal coordinates as those given in the samples. You *could* do that by using a floating point representation

.

Comment: I predict that [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) will win this one.

Comment: Can we assume that there are at least 3 points? Can we assume that the points are distinct? Are we required to support floating point coordinates?

Comment: @PeterTaylor the example indicates the last answer is true

Comment: May we overwrite the input?

Comment: The problem with treating collinear points consistently is there are rounding issues. We should be allowed to make mistakes.

Comment: @JanDvorak 1) You can overwrite the input if that is useful for you. 2) Collinearity detection: perform it up to your rounding ability, or use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic if you dare

Comment: @belisarius so, I am allowed to assume floats are infinitely precise

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes.

Comment: You might also want reasonable running time (eg. under 1 sec for examples) to avoid brute force check-every-possibility solutions.

Comment: @randomra Why not allow brute-force solutions? I don't think they can get substantially shorter than polynomial solutions.

Comment: @randomra No time limits, No specific algorithm requirement. Brute force it if that makes you happy :)

Comment: Yes, that answers my questions. Thanks.

Comment: There's a typo in sample 1.  The output contains a point `{9.5,14.9}` but no such point exists in the input.  I think the `{9.5,4.9}` in the input is supposed to be `{9.5,14.9}`.

Comment: @cardboard_box Thank you! The "1" was unintentionally deleted while editing the list

Answer (score 2):

#### Ruby, 168 characters

```ruby
C=->q{r=[]
f=m=q.sort[0]
t=-0.5
(_,_,t,*f=q.map{|x,y|a=x-f[0]
b=y-f[1]
[0==(d=a*a+b*b)?9:(-t+e=Math.atan2(b,a)/Math::PI)%2,-d,e,x,y]}.sort[0]
r<<=f)while
!r[1]||f!=m
r}
```

This ruby code also uses the gift wrapping algorithm. The function `C` accepts an array of points and returns the convex hull as array.

Example:

```
>p C[[[4.4, 14], [6.7, 15.25], [6.9, 12.8], [2.1, 11.1], [9.5, 14.9], 
     [13.2, 11.9], [10.3, 12.3], [6.8, 9.5], [3.3, 7.7], [0.6, 5.1], [5.3, 2.4], 
     [8.45, 4.7], [11.5, 9.6], [13.8, 7.3], [12.9, 3.1], [11, 1.1]]]

[[5.3, 2.4], [11, 1.1], [12.9, 3.1], [13.8, 7.3], [13.2, 11.9], [9.5, 14.9], [6.7, 15.25], [4.4, 14], [2.1, 11.1], [0.6, 5.1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica 151

still work in progress

```
f = For[t = Sort@#; n = 1; l = Pi; a = ArcTan; c@1 = t[[1]],
       n < 2 || c@n != c@1, 
       n++,
      (l = a @@ (# - c@n); c[n + 1] = #) & @@
      t[[Ordering[Mod[a@## - l, 2 Pi] & @@ (#2 - #1) & @@@ Tuples@{{c@n}, t}, 1]]]] &
```

testing:

```
ClearAll[a, c, t];
s = {{1, 0}, {0.68957, 0.283647}, {0.909487, 0.644276}, {0.0361877, 0.803816}, 
     {0.583004, 0.91555}, {-0.748169, 0.210483}, {-0.553528, -0.967036}, 
     {0.316709, -0.153861}, {-0.79267, 0.585945}, {-0.700164, -0.750994}, 
     {0.452273, -0.604434}, {-0.79134, -0.249902}, {-0.594918, -0.397574}, 
     {-0.547371, -0.434041}, {0.958132, -0.499614}, {0.039941, 0.0990732}, 
     {-0.891471, -0.464943}, {0.513187, -0.457062}, {-0.930053, 0.60341}, 
     {0.656995, 0.854205}};
f@s
Show[Graphics@Line@Table[c@i, {i, n}], 
     ListPlot[{t, Table[c@i, {i, n}]}, 
     PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Medium], PointSize[Large]}, 
     PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## CoffeeScript, 276:

```
f=($)->z=$[0];e.r=Math.atan2(e.x-z.x,e.y-z.y)for e in $;$.sort((x,y)->(x.r>y.r)-(x.r<y.r));(loop(a=$[i-1]||$[$.length-1];b=$[i];c=$[i+1]||$[0];break if!b;s=(b.x-a.x)*(c.y-b.y)-(b.y-a.y)*(c.x-b.x);break if s<0||!s&&(a.x-b.x)*(b.x-c.x)<0;$.splice i,1))for i in [$.length-1..0];$
```

If the function needs not be accessible, remove `f=` to shave off two more characters.

Input/output is a single array of points, with each point being defined by the `x,y` properties. The input array is modified, as well as returned (if the latter not required, remove the last two characters).

Explanation may be added later.

Test suite (won't work in oldIE):

```
alert JSON.stringify f({x:e[0], y:e[1]} for e in JSON.parse "
{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, ...}
".replace(/{/g,"[").replace(/}/g,"]"))
```

suggested test environment: http://coffeescript.org/

Comment: I tried it with `{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {1, 3}}` and it returned `[{"x" : 1, "y" : 1, "r" : 0}, {"x" : 1, "y" : 3, "r" : 0}, "x" : 2, 
   "y" : 2, "r" : 0.78..}]` while I think the correct answer is some permutation of `{{3, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 1}}`

Comment: @belisarius issue with points collinear with the first one sometimes producing incorrect hull fixed

Comment: @belisarius please add this as a test case to the question.

Comment: It seems to work properly now :)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <strike>209 205</strike> 195

```
from math import*
s=lambda(a,b),(c,d):atan2(d-b,c-a)
def h(l):
 r,t,p=[],pi/2,min(l)
 while 1:
    q=min(set(l)-{p},key=lambda q:(s(p,q)-t)%(2*pi));m=s(p,q);r+=[p]*(m!=t);p=q;t=m
    if p in r:return r
```

Uses a gift wrapping algorithm.  The result starts with the leftmost point and wraps counter-clockwise.

Example: `h([(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (1, 3)])` returns `[(1, 3), (1, 1), (3, 3)]`

Comment: Don't you need a `print` to get the output?

Comment: I thought by "output" you meant the output of the function.  Do you want the function to print the result instead of return it?

Comment: I thought that requiring `the output list can be in any reasonable format` was clear enough. Do you think it needs to be explicitly stated?

Comment: It seems your output points doesn't always match the input ones if floating point is used. For example `h([(0, 1), (0,1), (0.1 , 1)])` gives me `[(0, 1), (0.10000000000000001, 1)]`

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>327</s> 301 bytes

```cpp
#import<bits/stdc++.h>
using V=std::complex<double>;using W=std::deque<V>;W f(W x){V m=x[0],r,c;double v=imag(m),t,g,s=1;for(V a:x)c=m=imag(a-m)>0?a:m,v=fmin(imag(a),v);W p;do{p.push_back(r=c);g=4;for(V a:x)m=c=a!=r?t=std::arg(s*(a-r)),t<g|t==M_PI?g=t,a:c:c;s=imag(m)-v?s:-1;}while(m!=p[0]);return p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVJNc9MwEL3nV6jDoTF1hL5l2VZ65sAMp/QATMd1XddDnRjbCZkJ@e1hJTkt0GE4cPLu2923b59Vdt2iLsvT6U3Tdpt@zO@acXg3jPfl1RV@XM62Q7Ou0coCkqblpu2eqn1@v9nePVXLLBRvQvG@@rat8tUyu0EP8xu0jw4r1Nr9J/Il7uMyCzNoZ5u2qOdtFI9xHQ@WZg@bfr5CRbqPStuGarFooyW5LtI23tmHtlnPAxzFuwjoOyA7dLjbDo@3d0X5dd7bMspqK37ham1piwvbX49BXdHX8@EtMPcRrM7rH6O1H24/vr@u7RgXaZmW2XCWtthdD@mCZsfvj81TNW8vbAdXRFlfjdt@DeuPp3D5umiroSvKCsGObNasR9QWoDY6zFCw4w/Hls2a2sOB4hhRfIzRgUHEfMQh4j6iITpmM1Rsxw3abEeKLJgKwxGA7khf2Keu5JahEqI83@f5ZXwJLceQX35eQ/Z3LQy0CCxAjPCbFdYQS8xkyAxkDCdBKIWEYuoSg6WfMZDMQDDHzBeNl08w93M8kCQxgv5wIhQ01i4mWMVIBjrpcIZFYEuwAHYR2oBUunnlE@7IdCCGBcb5RKc25yj9zTQ2mcZem8b@wzTufmCMiN8LW6fvgk5nJUaCiwSzhCsx3WqIEYlHlRBMq3ApwYQrmmhfSAhPqArtMuGECIcaKqX3bkGwFtBgPDUlIuGBBApScsnAGQiN0sAZWDiFxHiYSp4oeuYxTPmVMpFGAHtg0YRQJXy7lsQYEViEZExzDysiBBfPLJSHbiaMIexFjRGGBjXcaKnPA1JorqnHgYWIyS8jE8pZgI1RVLx4Axqc0RjEEM3ZxJMYKs48ShjBJ88op85iB0tN1IsgA2ZK7s0n/LxWSWWM9MZLwYj0L@f56XDrHg5//XD4Px/O8fQT)

Another implementation of the gift wrapping algorithm. Slightly golfed less:

```cpp
#import<bits/stdc++.h>
using V=std::complex<double>;
using W=std::deque<V>;
W f(W x){
  V m=x[0],r,c;
  double v=imag(m),t,g,s=1;
  // find topmost point
  for(V a:x)
    c=m=imag(a-m)>0?a:m,
    v=fmin(imag(a),v);
  W p;
  do{
    p.push_back(r=c);
    g=4;
    // loop to find the smallest angle t
    for(V a:x)
      m=c=a!=r?
        t=std::arg(s*(a-r)),t<g|t==M_PI?
          g=t,a
        :
          c
      :
        c;
    // are we wrapping over or under?
    s=imag(m)-v?s:-1;
  // loop until we've gone all the way around
  }while(m!=p[0]);
  return p;
}
```